.NET 8 MAUI Button Binding with CommunityToolkit.MVVM
This is the method I wish to trigger in my code behind using the ComunityToolkit.MVVMpackage.
My ViewModel
[RelayCommand]
public async Task CreateBookingCommand()
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(BookingCreate)); 
}

my View
<Button Text="Place Request" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
        Command="{Binding CreateBookingCommand}"/>

and this is the error I get when I run in debug mode.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)    XFC0045 Binding: Property "CreateBookingCommand" 

From my understanding the nugget package is supposed to auto generate a property trigger but that doesn't seem to be happening. I'm using .NET 8 and version 8.2.2 of the CommunityToolkit.MVVM package

According to the RelayCommand attribute, when you RelayCommand attribute on a method, such as CreateBooking, it will generate a command like this:
private RelayCommand? createBookingCommand;

public IRelayCommand CreateBookingCommand => createBookingCommand ??= new RelayCommand(CreateBooking);

So, you only need to remove the Command suffix for the method name and it works,
[RelayCommand]
public async Task CreateBooking()
{
    ......

or since it's asynchronous methods, add a Async suffix seems better, also works
[RelayCommand]
public async Task CreateBookingAsync()
{
    ......

For more info, please refer to RelayCommand attribute

Glad it helps! Happy coding!
